# import statement doesn't throw any error when a exported property is not defined in the export file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

while checking import/ export feature, it was surprising to see that if a named property is used in import and it is not defined in the exported file than it does not throw any error?

below is the example

#### _export.js

```
export const ALPHA = 'alpha';
export const BETA = 'beta';
```

#### _import.js

```
import {ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA} from './export_'

console.log("alpha is ", ALPHA);
console.log("beta is", BETA);
console.log("gamma is", GAMMA);
```

Here `GAMMA` is not defined in *_export.js* but do not throw any error regarding this in *_import.js* ?

I was facing this issue as I have accidentally imported a wrong file ( same file name in 2 directories) in `import` statement but it does not throw any error that the given exported named property is not found in the file.

Is this behavior is correct?

or

Is there any linting rule in linter ( eg. eslint)  available which identifies such mistake and throws error or warning to the developer?

Comment: Your ES6 runtime should throw on this.

Comment: No, it is not throwing any error.

Comment: Which runtime are you using, native module support? A transpiled commonjs module probably won't throw.

Comment: I am using `babel-node` in macOS and testing this feature inside sublime text 3 using build system. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, esLint doesnt provide this check out of the box.
You may want to use [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import).
I use it and it throws an error of `import/named` when a module wasn't found.
For example:

> MyModule not found in '../../modules'

[examples](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/named.md)

Comment: eslint already gives an error when module not found but the issue is when I have the same module name (file name ) in the different directory but with different content.